# Prestashop: is there a way to limit invoice address to only one?

Tags: php, prestashop

I need to limit the invoice address registration to 1. So, no more than 1 invoice address, but multiple options shipping addresses.

Is it possible? How to? I'm thinking about building custom controllers for this task, but maybe there are faster ways to do it.

Comment: The 'faster' way is to edit all the tpl of tour template, remove all the call to action to add another address :). Maybe a little override of AddressesController, and AddressController

Comment: I don't think so, since as I wrote, I need 1 invoice address AND multiple optional shipping addresses.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :). Override of Address (the class) and one more field in db like a flag. And override of AddressController, and also the Authentication I guess. Don't forget the tpl(s).. At the moment I don't think there is a faster way

Answer (score 0):

Without any custom change in the code, it doesn't seem to be possible to differentiate addresses in the address table (because there is no column to indicates that it is an invoice address or delivery address).

If you need to achieve this, we recommend you to add a new column in the table DB_PREFIX_address table to identify the type of the address. You will also have to make changes in checkout and registration page to the save type of the address.